# Get User Details From IdentityDbContext by joining to User Details entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two DB Contexts.

They are IdentityDbContext( referenced by :ApplicationDbContext), and DbEntites (ie. DbContext).

The IdentityDbContext is only for Authentication and UserManager (doesn't contain User details Entity).

The DbEntites is for the rest of the entities except the User (also contains User Details entity).

**IdentityDbContext**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
   public int? ContactID { get; set; } // User Details Id
}
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        // I want to initialize the Login Entities Automatically So 
        //no Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(null); is used
    }
}
```

**DBEntities**

```
public class DBEntities : DbContext
{
    public DBEntities()
       : base("name=DefaultConnection")
   {
       Database.SetInitializer<DBEntities>(null);
   }
   public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; } // User Details Entity
}
```

Now I want to List the UserNames from the ApplicationUser and also their Details like Name, Address, etc which is in DbEntites.

I tried to include the

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
   public int? ContactID { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("ContactID")]
   public Contact Contact { get; set; }
}
public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
```

to the ApplicationDbContext, but it just gives me the following error whenever i try to get data from ApplicationUser

```
The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created.
```

I tried using foreign key for the ContactID in the database. But still the same error. How do i solve the Problem?

Please any suggestions or workaround.

**Update:** Basically I just want to use the **Contact** Entity in the ApplicationDbContext without the "The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since the database was created." error and still be able to use it in DbEntites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating a model for the `AspNetUsers` and `AspNetRoles` and using in `DbEntites`. As my `DbEntites` has `SetInitializer to null`, it solved my problem.

```
public class AspNetUsers
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int? ContactID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ContactID")]
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AspNetRoles> Roles { get; set; } 
}

public class AspNetRoles
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AspNetUsers> Users { get; set; } 
}
```

In DbEntites

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUsers>()
                .HasMany(c => c.Roles)
                .WithMany(i => i.Users)
                .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("UserId").MapRightKey("RoleId").ToTable("AspNetUserRoles"));


public DbSet<AspNetRoles> AspNetRoleses { get; set; }
public DbSet<AspNetUsers> AspNetUserses { get; set; }
```

This might not be ideal way to solve the problem, but which one is anyways?